# Magento 2. add title attribute on topmenu on frontend

Tags: magento2.3

I want to add a title attribute on the topmenu in Magento 2. for example `<a href="category_url" title="category_name">category_name</a>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For that you would want to rewrite the `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` blocks `_getHtml` method. [Here is a link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341438/how-to-override-gethtml-function-form-topmenu-php-file-in-magento-2#341483) to another post that answered how to create the `<preference>` to rewrite that block.