# How to override _getHtml() function form topmenu.php file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides, topmenu

I want to override _getHtml() function from topmenu.php file using block. So Please help me

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Can you please tell here what you want to perform?

Comment: i want to simply override topmenu.php file function using block.

Comment: override file working for you?

Comment: i will try this thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override block by preference in **di.xml** file in your module :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

Now, Create **Topmenu.php** file

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Html/Topmenu.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Topmenu extends Template implements IdentityInterface
{
    //add override code here
}
```